# Why is my textarea value not changing from getDocumentById?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My program is supposed to find the frequency of characters in a string, which it does marvelously. However, it only does it from the initial value of a textarea. I need it to update. Any thought? This is homework so if you could keep your answers on the more "guidline style" than the "copy and paste style", that would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>THE BEST HOMEWORK EVA!</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.addEventListener("load", start, false);

            var string;
            var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
            var freq = [];

            function start() {
                var button = document.getElementById("countButton");
                button.addEventListener("click", getFrequency, false);
            }

            function getFrequency() {
                string = document.getElementById("inputElement").innerHTML;
                var totalCharacters = string.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                    freq[i] = 0;
                    for (var j = 0; j < string.length; j++) {
                        if (string.charAt(j) == arr[i]) {
                            ++freq[i];
                        }
                    }
                }
                document.write(document.getElementById("inputElement").innerHTML);
                //initialize table
                document.writeln("<table style = \"text-align: center\" border = \"1\">");
                document.writeln("<th>Letter</th><th>Count</th><th>Frrequency</th>")
                //construct table by row
                for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                    document.writeln("<tr><td>" + arr[i] + "</td>");
                    document.writeln("<td>" + freq[i] + "</td>");
                    document.writeln("<td>" + (freq[i] / totalCharacters * 100) + "%</td></tr>");
                }
                //end table
                document.writeln("</table>");
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Computer Letter Frequency</h1>
        <form action ="#">
            <h2>Input:<input id="countButton" type="button" value="Count!" /></h2>
            <p>
                <textarea id="inputElement" rows="12" cols="80" >Enter your text here....</textarea>
            </p>
            <h2>Results:</h2>
            <div id="outputElement"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is meant by  "I need it to update"

Comment: sorry. I need it to be dynamic so if you change the content of the textarea, then it updates.

Comment: so what is the purpose of count button?If you dynamically want to update the table then this button should not be there

Comment: take a look at my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `innerHTML` of the `<textarea>` doesn't change when you type in it, so:

```
string = document.getElementById("inputElement").innerHTML
```

will always set `string` to the same thing no matter how much the value of the inputElement has changed.

Its `value` property changes though, so you'll have better luck with that over `innerHTML`.

Comment: Are you a wizard? Thank you so much that worked perfectly!

Comment: No, not a wizard haha; but I'm glad I could help. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> I need it to update.

This part is quite confusing to me so I have made this changes.

1. As soon as you type in text area, It will update the counts.(Dynamic update)
2. When text field is empty it wont show the table.
3. You don't need to pre-define the characters.
4. It will also include white space and special characters.
5. No need of click button.

Here is the code. For html part you can click on [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/U4byYz9LczdOrC26nBa8?p=preview)

```
window.onload = function(){  // Execute the function when window is completly laoded
          var alphaObject = [];
          var txtArea = document.getElementById('inputElement');
          txtArea.addEventListener('keyup',function(event){// update table on key up from text area
              alphaObject.length = 0; // empty the array which contain characters
              var getTxtLength = txtArea.value.length; 
              if(getTxtLength ===0){
                 // dont show table if text area is empty
                 document.getElementById('outputElement').classList.add('hide');
              }
              else{
                //break the input string and put all characters in array
                alphaObject = txtArea.value.split('');
                var m = _getWordCnt();
                document.getElementById('outputElement').classList.remove('hide');
                document.getElementById('outputElement').classList.add('show');
              _createTable(m,txtArea.value.length);
              }

          })

            /* This function create an object. For example if my string is "aabbc"
            it will return an object {a:2,b:2,c:1}
            which mean there is 2 occurence of a & b and 1 occurence of c
            Used reduce function of js array to acheive this
            */
            function _getWordCnt(){
                     return alphaObject.reduce(function(prev,next){
                     prev[next] = (prev[next] + 1) || 1;
                    return prev;
                    },{});
                  }

            /*Creating table tbody and updating the values

            */

            function _createTable(obj,stringLength){
                var tbody = document.createElement('TBODY');
                var crtRow="";
                 for(var key in obj){ // looping through the object
                       var charOccurence = ((obj[key])/stringLength)*100;
                      crtRow += '<tr><td>'+key+'</td><td>'+obj[key]+'</td><td>'+charOccurence+' %</td></tr>'
                  }
                 document.getElementById("tabBody").innerHTML="";
                 document.getElementById('tabBody').innerHTML=(crtRow);
            }
}
```

[DEMO & FULL CODE](https://plnkr.co/edit/U4byYz9LczdOrC26nBa8?p=preview)